# Segmentation fault with function

Tags: c

I am receiving a segmentation fault right after my first printf, printf("Original:\n"); Notice: grades.csv is an excel file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>




void getGradesFromFile(const char *filename,
                            int size,
                            char line[],
                int studentI_D[],
                int test1,
                int test2,
                int test3,
                char grades[]);



void insertionSort(int length,
                   int studentI_D[],
           char list[]);

void flushScanf();

void binarySearch(int size,
                int target, 
        int studentID[]);

void printArray(int size,
        char A[*],
        int B[*],
        int test1,
        int test2,
        int test3,
        char grades[]);


int main(void)
{
  char grades[2];
  int size = 60;
  char str[size];
  int studentID [7];
  char letter;
  int exam1, exam2, exam3;
  int num;

  printf("Original:\n");
  getGradesFromFile("grades.csv", size, str, studentID, exam1, exam2, exam3, grades);// function call
  printArray(size, str, studentID, exam1, exam2, exam3, grades);

  printf("Sorted:");
  insertionSort(size, studentID, grades);// inscertion sort function call
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Enter student ID and -1 to quit");
  scanf("%d", num);
  flushScanf();

printf("Hello World");
  while (num != -1){
  if (num > 99999 && num < 1000000){
  binarySearch(size, num, studentID);


}
  else {
 printf ("Error and enter again [100000, 999999] and -1 to quit");
}
exit;
  }




  return 0;
}  // end of main
/*              
*Function name: getNumbersFromFile
* 
*Input Parameters: const char *filename, int size, float number[]
* 
*Desription: gets numbers from the file and checks for errors
* 
*Return value: filename
*/
```

I am unsure if the data is obtained correctly with this function, appreciate any assistance with this function. The function's role is to get data from an excel file and put it into a string.

```
void getGradesFromFile(const char *filename,
                int size,
                            char line[],
                           int studentI_D[], 
                            int test1,
                int test2,
                            int test3,
                            char grades[])
{
  FILE* pData = fopen("grades.csv","r+");
  int i = 0;
  if (pData == NULL) {// opens file grades.csv
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n", filename);// error handling statement
    exit(1);
  }


  while (fgets(line,sizeof(line), pData) != NULL){
sscanf(line, "%s, %d, %d, %d, %s", studentI_D[i], &test1, &test2, &test3, 
grades[i]);
i++;


}


  if (fclose(pData)== EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file.\n", filename);// close file
    exit(2);
  }
}


void insertionSort(int length, int studentID[], char grades[])
{
    int i, key, key1, j;
   for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
   {
       key = studentID[i];
       key1= grades[i];
       j = i-1;

       while (j >= 0 && studentID[j] > key)
       {
           studentID[j+1] = studentID[j];
           grades[j+1] = grades[j];
           j = j-1;
       }
       studentID[j+1] = key;
       grades[i+j] = key1;
   }

}

void flushScanf()
{ 
  while(getchar() != '\n')
        ;
}



void binarySearch(int size, int target, int student[])
{
     char *locn;
     int  first = 0;
     int last = size - 1;
     int mid;
     bool found = false;

    while (first <= last) {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (target > student[mid]) {
        first = mid + 1;
    } else if (target < student[mid]) {
    last = mid - 1;
    } else {
    *locn = mid;
    found = true;
    break;
    }
    }

}




void printArray(int size, 
                char A[size],
                int B[],
                int test1,
                int test2,
                int test3,
                char grades[])
{

    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
    printf("%s, %d, %d, %d, %s", A[j], B[j], test1, test2, test3, grades[j] );
  }

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(line)` --> `size`, `studentI_D[i]` --> `studentI_D + i`, `%d` for `studentI_D`

Comment: Fyi, `exit;` is highly likely *not* going to do what you think it will. Turn up your warnings to *pedantic* levels, treat them as errors, and fix *everything* that is flagged. [Example](http://pastebin.com/8FcZwvLn).

Comment: Also, It is not actually read from the file.

Comment: I think you have tried to write way too much code, then you finally ran it, the program exploded and now you don't know what to do.  You must learn to build up your program piece by piece, and test as you go.  Also, read the documentation for `sscanf`, read about arrays and strings, and learn to use a debugger such as `gdb`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I am still experiencing segmentation fault issues, please help.

Comment: This is awfully close to your previous questions ([Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646638/passing-argument-1-of-%c3%a2getgradesfromfile%c3%a2-makes-integer-from-pointer-without-a-c) and [Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580059/creating-a-student-exam-average-in-c)).  You've still not fixed the `exit;` problem — which is what triggered the recollection that I've seen this code before.  It's an odd mistake to be making in the first place; it fingerprints your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sscnaf logic in getGradesFromFile. you want input for grade using %s not %c.

```
void getGradesFromFile(const char *filename,
                int size,
                            char line[],
                           int studentI_D[],
                            int test1,
                int test2,
                            int test3,
                            char grades[])
{
  FILE* pData = fopen("grades.csv","r+");
  int i = 0;
  if (pData == NULL) {// opens file grades.csv
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n", filename);// error handling statement
    exit(1);
  }


  while (fgets(line,sizeof(line), pData) != NULL){
sscanf(line, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c", &studentI_D[i], &test1, &test2, &test3,
&grades[i]);
i++;

}
```